# Passing Json using JsonResult not working properly

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I am trying to create pie Chart using `JsonResult`and Chart.js

Here is my code which I am trying

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/User/Pie/",
                data: { 'campaignID': 5 },
                success: function (data) {
                    pieData = data;              
                    new Chart(document.getElementById("pie").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error:" + JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Pie(string campaignID)
        {
            try
            {
                return Json("[{ value:  40, color: \"#000000\"},{value: 60,color: \"#01dfde\"},{value: 60,color: \"#01dfde\"}]", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Which is not working. I am getting Json from controller successfully, but Chart is not visible.

If I put Json in pieData Statically, it is working all well

```
pieData = [{ value:  40, color: \"#000000\"},{value: 60,color: \"#01dfde\"},{value: 60,color: \"#01dfde\"}];
```

I have also tried Json.Parse

Comment: just check for any errors in console.

Comment: Nope, there isn't any error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass c# array to `Json` method, it will convert it to json itself:

```
var pieData= new[]
             {
                new { value = 40, color = "#000000" },
                new { value = 60,  color="#01dfde"},
                new { value=60, color = "#01dfde"}
              };
return Json(pieData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is working all well. So that's mean, If I am passing directly. It is passing as a single string?

Comment: yes, i am not sure the way you were doing will work or not, but we just pass c# object to ``JSON()`` and it converts in to json for us